# Is slicing matrix a view or copy in cvxopt?

Tags: matrix

It is known that Numpy basic matrix slicing will generate a view, whereas advanced slicing a copy. Is this true in cvxopt? I tried

```
from cvxopt import spmatrix
import numpy as np
A = spmatrix([2,-1,2,-2,1,4,3], [1,2,0,2,3,2,0], [0,0,1,1,2,3,4])
A_view = A[0:3,0:3]           # basic slicing
A_cp = A[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]     # advanced slicing
np.may_share_memory(A,A_view) # returned false
np.may_share_memory(A,A_cp)   # returned false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a sparse matrix.  Numpy doesn't have sparse matrices, and I think neither `scipy.sparse` nor `cvxopt` use memoryviews for sparse matrices.

Even for dense matrices it appears that `cvxopt` uses a low level Python API instead of something like Cython.  I don't see any references to memoryview interfaces so perhaps even dense matrices in `cvxopt` use copying instead of views.

This might be the relevant function for sparse matrix indexing in the cvxopt source, where you will find a lot of copying.
https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/blob/master/src/C/sparse.c#L2791

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. I need a package that can retrieve sparse submatrix view and armadillo looks suitable for my purpose: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat.